# Related Terms Block Based on Terms Fields

Tags: 7, views

I am not sure where to begin except experimenting with contextual filters which is not getting me very far. I am trying to display taxonomy terms in a block based on if a certain field has the same info that is on the same taxonomy page.

For example

```
Current term page = Radioshack
Radioshack has the fields: 
Term Field City: San diego
Term Field Type: Electronic

And the terms I want to list would be 
Term: Frys Electronics
Term Field City: San Diego
Term Field Type: Electronics Store

Term: Best Buy
Term Field City: La Jolla
Term Field Type: Electronics Store
```

So if you notice they all have the same type which is electronic store so it would display those 2 terms on the current page which is radioshack and any other terms with the same type electronics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this done by adding my code in into my contextual filter which would be Taxonomy Term:[You term field name].

This is the code I used.

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
$path = explode('/', $path);
$termname = array_pop($path);
$termname = str_replace("-", " ", $termname);
$terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($termname );
$term = reset($terms);
$term->tid;
$term_list = taxonomy_term_load($term->tid);
return $term_list->field_companies_industry['und']['0']['value'];
```