# Get taxonomy terms page based on exposed filters value

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've created two taxonomy vocabs: Language and Genre. LANGUAGE consists of the following terms: English,Spanish,French,etc and GENRE consists of Rock,Pop,etc.

Am using the taxonomy term page view with exposed filters for language and genre.

When am in a page that list all songs under the term english, the filter for genre and language also appears. All good till here.

Now, If i select spanish from the filter..i want the term page to reload and show the relative results.
 How can i work this out???

Comment: Take a look at this, I did something similar to what you're asking. If it helps upvote please. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31906/related-terms-block-based-on-terms-fields

Comment: not even close...neways thanks for the reply man..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier if you will use just one vocabulary. Smt like this:

```
English
- Rock
- Pop
- etc.
Spanish
- Pop
- Rock
- etc.
```

Then you can use [hierarchical_select module](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) to filter exposed lists automatically.

If you can't change vocabulary structure, you should use `hook_form_alter()` ...

Comment: with my structure if i list songs with rock term all rock songs from all languages will get displayed...yeah your structure won't do but did gave me a different approach, will be helpful in some other project...Well was hoping there must be some module to magically do that...thanks